# Use perl REST::Client and multi-part form to post image to Confluence

Tags: perl, rest, curl, confluence, confluence-rest-api

How can I attach an image to an existing Confluence page, using their latest REST API, from Perl via the REST::Client module?

This may be a perl question (I may be posting an image incorrectly), or a Confluence question (their API docs may be missing a required detail such as a required header that is being quietly added by curl), or both.

I have established a connection object, $client, using the REST::Client module.  I have verified that $client is a valid connection by performing a $client->GET to a known Confluence page ID, which correctly returns the page's details.

I attempt to upload an image, using:

```
$headers = {Accept => 'application/json',
        Authorization => 'Basic ' . encode_base64($user . ':' .
        $password),
        X_Atlassian_Token => 'no-check',
        Content_Type => 'form-data',
        Content => 
        [ file => ["file1.jpg"], ]};

$client->POST('rest/api/content/44073843/child/attachment', $headers);
```

... and the image doesn't appear on the attachments list.

I've packet-sniffed the browser whilst uploading an image there, only to find that it uses the prototype API that is being deprecated.  I'd hoped that I could just stand on Atlassian's shoulders in terms of seeing exactly what their post stream looks like, and replicating that... but I don't want to use the API that's being deprecated, since they recommend against it.

The curl example of calling the Confluence API to attach a file that they give at https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-rest-api/confluence-rest-api-examples, when my host, filename, and page ID are substituted in, does post the attachment.

I formerly specified comment in my array of Content items, but removed that during debugging to simplify things since the documentation said it was optional.

One thing I'm unclear about is getting the contents of the file into the post stream.  In the curl command, the @ accomplishes that.  In REST::Client, I'm not sure if I have to do something more than I did, to make that happen.

I can't packet-sniff the outgoing traffic because our server only allows https, and I don't know how (or if it's even possible) to set the REST::Client module or one of its underlying modules to record the SSL info to a log file so that Wireshark can pick it up and decode the resulting TLS traffic, the way one can with the environment variable for Chrome or Firefox.  I also don't have access to server logs.  So I don't know what the request I'm actually sending looks like (if I did, I could probably say, "OK, it looks wrong right HERE" or "But it looks right?!"). I am therefore unfortunately at a loss as to how to debug it so blindly.

A similar question about posting multipart forms using REST::Client was asked by someone else, more generically, back in April of last year, but received no responses. I'm hoping that since mine is more specific, someone can tell me what I might be doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've automated with Confluence, but don't have easy access right now to test. In your example I can't see where the file (image) content is uploaded. The REST::Client spec for POST is ( $url, [$body_content, %$headers] ) - so do you need to load the body_content from the image file?

Comment: I believe that the [ "file1.jpg" ] accomplishes that, per the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You should be capturing your post response like so:

```
my $response = $client->POST('rest/api/content/44073843/child/attachment', $headers);   print Dumper $response;
```

Also, the url you are using in the POST call is incomplete and won't work, you need the full url.